# Python Threading consumer being called before producer

Tags: python, multithreading

I wrote a simple python program to understand threading. This program has no thread blocking logic like time.sleep(x) but still I don't understand how possibly can consumer thread be called before producer thread.

Producer -> appends a numeric value to list
Consumer -> gets/prints the numeric value from this list.

How can consumer print even before producer generates the number?

```
import threading
import time
import datetime
from colorama import Fore as colorify


def main() -> None:

    data=[]

    threads = [

        threading.Thread(target=producer,args=(data,5),daemon=True),
        threading.Thread(target=consumer,args=(data,5),daemon=True)

    ]

    [t.start() for t in threads]

    [t.join() for t in threads]


    print(f"{colorify.YELLOW}Execution completed")

def producer(data: list, num:int) -> None:

    for i in range(num):
        _t = datetime.datetime.now()
        sqrt=i*i
        data.append([i,_t])
        print(f"{colorify.BLUE} producer {i} {threading.get_ident()}")
        
def consumer(data : list, num: int) -> None:

    for i in data:
        item= i
        number=item[0]
        _t=item[1]
        print(f"{colorify.RED} consumer {number}  {threading.get_ident()}")


 output:
 producer 0 18064
 producer 1 18064
 producer 2 18064
 producer 3 18064
 consumer 0  8028
 consumer 1  8028
 consumer 2  8028
 consumer 3  8028
 producer 4 18064
Execution completed
0.0028671000036410987 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a race condition, and if the list was bigger and there were more elements in it you would only print the elements that were in the list the moment the second thread started, which is only a portion of the list.

Printing is also buffered so it doesn't happen at the order in which you call print, the actual printing is done when the buffer is full,and a context switch can happen even between writing to the list and printing, and the print buffer can be written to concurrently, so writing to buffers (including printing) is a race condition, and your entire code is a race condition.

You can flush the stdout using `flush=True` argument of print to avoid buffering, but to fix the race condition that happens when accessing elements you need to use a  [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), and you can also share a [lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) between the two threads to make sure adding to queue and printing will not be interrupted by a context switch.

```py
import threading
import time
import datetime
from colorama import Fore as colorify
import queue


def main() -> None:
    data = queue.Queue()
    lock = threading.Lock()
    threads = [

        threading.Thread(target=producer, args=(data, 5, lock), daemon=True),
        threading.Thread(target=consumer, args=(data, 5, lock), daemon=True)

    ]

    [t.start() for t in threads]

    [t.join() for t in threads]

    print(f"{colorify.YELLOW}Execution completed", flush=True)


def producer(data: queue.Queue, num: int, lock: threading.Lock) -> None:
    for i in range(num):
        _t = datetime.datetime.now()
        sqrt = i * i
        with lock:
            data.put([i, _t])
            print(f"{colorify.BLUE} producer {i} {threading.get_ident()}", flush=True)


def consumer(data: queue.Queue, num: int, lock: threading.Lock) -> None:
    for i in range(num):
        item = data.get()
        number = item[0]
        _t = item[1]
        with lock:
            print(f"{colorify.RED} consumer {number}  {threading.get_ident()}", flush=True)


main()
```

```
 producer 0 5692
 producer 1 5692
 producer 2 5692
 producer 3 5692
 producer 4 5692
 consumer 0  12644
 consumer 1  12644
 consumer 2  12644
 consumer 3  12644
 consumer 4  12644
Execution completed
```

note that the `flush` in this code is not needed, as the lock will prevent concurrent writes to stdout buffer.